# Why do JList selections occur twice?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a JList with some items. I've added a listener for when a item in the list is selected. Here is the code for what happens when an item in the list is selected:

```
private void questionaireNamesListValueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
    try {
        inputPanel.setEnabled(false);
        inputPanel.setVisible(false);
        inputTextField.setText("");
        inputStatusLabel.setText("");
        int questionaireIndex = questionaireNamesList.getSelectedIndex();

        // Why will this be printed twice?
        System.out.println("Questionaire Index: " + questionaireIndex);

        if (remoteQuestionServer.getQuestionCount(questionaireIndex) == 5) {
            answerQuestionButton.setEnabled(true);
            addQuestionButton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            addQuestionButton.setEnabled(true);
            answerQuestionButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can above I put a `System.out.print` statement in and every time I click on something in the list I get two ouputs for that item, eg.

```
Questionaire Index: 4
Questionaire Index: 4
Questionaire Index: 2
Questionaire Index: 2
Questionaire Index: 0
Questionaire Index: 0
Questionaire Index: 2
Questionaire Index: 2
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you change a selection, one or two events can occur, depending on the implementation.  If index #4 is selected and you click on the second item, then the following occurs:

- First, index #4 is UNSELECTED.  Depending on the model, `questionaireNamesList.getSelectedIndex()` can legally return either 2 or -1.
- second, index #2 is SELECTED.  At this point, `questionaireNamesList.getSelectedIndex()` will surely return 2.

Thus, there are two events fired.  The definition of how these events are generated allows leeway for different JVM implementations do go things slightly differently.

NOTE:  You should probably check the value of [`ListSelectionEvent#getValueIsAdjusting()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting()) to see if the event you are processing is one in a series of events.  You probably need to ignore all events where this returns `true`.

Comment: If index 4 is unselected then why would getSelectedIndex() return 4 and not -1?

Comment: You say if index #4 is UNSELECTED it can legally return 2 or -1. Why 2?

Comment: In my example, you have just selected #2, so it can legally tell you that nothing is selected, or that the new selection (#2) is the selection.

Comment: Ah I see now. So in my case when I have x selected and click y it prints y twice which you have covered here, strange that it works this way though. Anyway thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Correct answer, but I don't believe it is a matter of the implementation of the **JVM**. It is more a matter of the implementation of the ListSelectionModel, actually it is documented in [setValueIsAdjusting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setValueIsAdjusting(boolean) "ListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting")

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: When I said "different JVM implementations" I really meant "JVM" including the full set of libraries as part of the implementation.  I didn't mean to imply that the implementation details of the virtual machine itself would affect this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that good at English, I understand "JVM implementation" as (only) the Java Virtual Machine implementation... The libraries are part of the JRE in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Further to the answer by Eddie look at the getValueIsAdjusting method on the event.