# A jlist is populated with an arrayList.When an item is clicked,information should be displayed in a jTextArea.But it is doing it twice

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Here is the constructor for the frame

```
     public LibraryFrame() {
    mod1 = new javax.swing.DefaultListModel();
    books = new ArrayList<>();
    Book b1 = new Book("book1","aAuthor","aPublisher","aIsbn",5,0);
    books.add(b1);
    mod1.addElement(b1.title);
    initComponents();
}
```

Here is the listener

```
        private void viewStockListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
           int selected = viewStockList.getSelectedIndex();
    String info = books.get(selected).title;
    viewStockArea.insert(info,0);
}
```

When I select an item for the list the title is inserted into the text area twice(which ends up being book1book1 )

I have researched as much as i could about the listener and i was not able to find a solution.Appreciate any help

Edit:Thanks to kentcdodds,the solution was found.Essentially that listener creates two events.Look at his answer for furhter explanation.Here is the finished code that works correctly

```
  private void viewStockListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
          if (!evt.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                    int selected = viewStockList.getSelectedIndex();
    String info = books.get(selected).title;
    viewStockArea.insert(info,0);  
          }


}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you i have never heard of an SSCCE.I will keep it in mind for future submissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how JList selection changed events work. It activates two events. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646302/971592) to a similar question.

Comment: but what if none is selected?

Comment: i meant, what if none of the item is selected before, and then i select 1 item. The link u posted has like, 2 events get fired, 1st for un-selecting the one which is selected, and the 2nd for the one we just selected.

Comment: I see, good point. I can't quite remember. I also know that if you don't click but use the mouse to change the selection it only fires once as well. You'll have to handle that on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your help:)Upon looking at your link i found the solution.I will edit the question to show the solution.Thanks alot

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you don't click but use the arrow keys then it only fires once. Glad it helped David. Please accept it as the answer so future comers will know you were satisfied.